# trying to parse remote site with curl

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code. Trying to parse a login page of a remote site to retreive a hidden token. Once I retreive the token I can then log into the remote site from my php page. However, I've having trouble parsing the hidden token on the remote login page. Here is my code

```
$url = 'http://uk.songselect.com/account/login/';

$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);





//run the process and fetch the document
$doc = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

//echo $doc;


// extract __RequestVerificationToken input field
$token = explode('<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="',$doc);
$token = explode('" />',$token[1]);
$token = $token[0];

echo $token;
```

If get back the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in songselect.php on line 24
```

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: The first explode fails. If you're looking for a substring in a string use `str_pos` and `substr`.

Comment: What are you trying to do by `explode()`?

Comment: Consider using regex or even parse the html dom elements and then get the value of this input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://uk.songselect.com/account/login/';

$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);


//run the process and fetch the document
$doc = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 


// extract __RequestVerificationToken input field
preg_match('#<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.*?)"#is', $doc, $match);

echo $token = $match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Halycon mentioned, your explode fails.

IMO Dom parsing will be easier:

save the page html into $html var, replace

```
$doc = curl_exec($ch);
```

with:

```
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

and then grab the input value using dom parsing and xpath:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xp->query('//input[@name="__RequestVerificationToken"]');
$node = $nodes->item(0);
$v = $node->getAttribute('value');
```

$v now holds __RequestVerificationToken value

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_match()`, you can retrieve the token as follows:

```
preg_match('/<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="([^"]*)" \/>/',$doc,$matches);
$token=$matches[1];
```

The pattern can be improved. This one is just a quick example.